# Wrapper class for WIA/TWAIN for a C# application?

Tags: c#, wia, twain

Is there a wrapper class somewhere for WIA/TWAIN functionality in a C# application?

Every search I make points to the same old 2001 CodeProject page, there **has** to be something new out there, right?

Maybe I'm not looking in the right place. :P

I need something really simple, like:

```
Image myImage = wiaWrapper.GetImageFromScanner();
```

Done and done.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 8):

> #### [TwainDotNet](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet)

I've wrapped up the code from Thomas Scheidegger's article ([CodeProject: .NET TWAIN image scanning](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/twaindotnet.aspx)) into a [GitHub project](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet).

I've cleaned up the API a bit, added WPF support and several people have added other improvements. I've tried to keep the API simple but it is still a bit more complicated that what you've got there.

Also this question has some other options: [.NET Scanning API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276/net-scanning-api)

Comment: Well done! Any plans of making TwainDotNet available via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org)?

Comment: @CodeFox unfortunately I'm not actively working on the project any more. I'm happy to accept a pull request though ;-) However, NTwain looks more active at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Besides [TwainDotNet](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet) maintained by Luke, I have recently noticed [NTwain](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NTwain/) on NuGet ([project page on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/soukoku/twain-in-dotnet)).

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft

We publish [DotTwain](http://atalasoft.com/products/dottwain), which is a .NET TWAIN SDK.  It's royalty-free and is used in [InspectorTWAIN.com](http://InspectorTWAIN.com) to help certify TWAIN drivers (we're members of the TWAIN working group).

Our product is a .NET Assembly that wraps interop calls.

You could also take a look at [EZTwain](http://dosadi.com) from Dosadi, which is free.  I don't know how native the .NET support is, but they have a way of calling from .NET.

Comment: I've visited the DotTwain page but I can't find pricing anywhere. Any links you can provide on pricing please?

Comment: Go to the Buy page: http://www.atalasoft.com/buy/dotimage -- the current price is $525 for 1 SDK.  Additional ones are $175.  You can use DotImage Photo for free to process the images or use .NET Image/Bitmap.  No runtime-royalties.

Answer (score 0):

As for a WIA C# wrapper, I came across [ScanWIA](https://scanwia.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex. It doesn't have a whole lot of documentation. However, reading the source code might help.